# How do I reverse a buffer.toString() on a hex buffer?

Tags: javascript, buffer

```
  const uuidc = '9acf0decef304b229ea1560d4b3bf7d0';
  const packed = Buffer.from(uuidc, 'hex');
  const packedAndStringified = 'm:' + packed;
```

I have some keys stored in a redis database that were stored like above.  The problem is that once a string is appended to `pack` it is (I'm guessing) effectively converting the hex buffer into a binary string.

The stringified output looks something like: `K;��V��`

Is there any way for me to get `packedAndStringified` back to `packed`, and ultimately get the `uuidc` pulled back out?

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end

Here it should be `const packedAndStringified = 'm:' + packed.toString('hex');` ?

Comment: Somebody else already encoded it and set the redis keys up this way.  I need to get the data back out.